# How to plot copula using contourplots

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I want to contour plot some copula cases for illustrative purposes in a paper. New user here, so apologies if this is straightforward. An example (taken from another source) is below of what I had in mind.

I've been doing the following

```
\[ScriptCapitalD][\[Alpha]_] = CopulaDistribution[{"Clayton", \[Alpha]}, {UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}];

Table[ListPlot[RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD][\[Alpha]], 10^3], PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Alpha] = ", \[Alpha]}]], {\[Alpha], {1/2, 3, 10, 60, 500}}]
```

but that's not a counterplot.
[image]

Comment: Something like what `ContourPlot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD][1/5], {x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> All]` produces?

Answer (score 2):

```
dist[α_] = 
  CopulaDistribution[{"Binormal", α}, {NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[]}];

Table[
  ContourPlot[
    PDF[dist[α], {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}],
    PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 10, PlotPoints -> 100,
    ContourShading -> None,
    ContourStyle -> Lighter@Blue,
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.9],
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> False}
  ],
  {α, {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}}
]
```

[image: three contour plots]